# Union two tables with one different column

Tags: sql, db2

I have two almost identical tables except one column.

```
table1 
     id name amount
     1  nm1  15
     2  nm2  20

table1 
     id name amt
     1  nm1  15
     2  nm2  20
```

Now I have other joins but I want to avoid have it all twice but rather have more simple sql code.

At the moment I have to do all twice:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.amount from table1 t1 
       left outer join.......
  union all 
select t2.id, t2.name, t2.amt as amount from table2 t2 
       left outer join.......
```

I would like to have something like:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.amount from (select * from table1 union all select * from table2) t1
```

but this one column "amount" prevents it.

Is there a way how to handle it?

Comment: You have shown one table and the data is identical.

Comment: Why does `amount` prevent you from unioning? For a union, the column name does not matter, the datatype matters

Comment: Please show us the result that you want for this sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the `union all` before the `join`:

```
select t.id, t.name, t.amount, . . .
from (select t1.* from table1 t1 union all
      select t2.* from table2 t2
     ) t left outer join.......
```

Comment: Does this solve different amount column name for each table? (t1.amount, t2.amt)

Comment: @MichalPalko, the column name is immaterial.

Comment: @MichalPalko . . . In fact, it renames it to whatever is used in the first subquery.

Comment: Thank you. I can see it now. Problem was that tables were not totally same as I thought and thats why I thought it was problem with naming. However I will accept your answer.

Comment: @MichalPalko . . . This answers the question that you have asked.  You can list the columns explicitly in the subquery if the columns are not the same.